# I am getting an error whilst running android cordova app on phone

Tags: android, cordova

This is the error i receive when I input the  command cordova run android and I tried to fix using some threads but nothing works

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
    java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupporte
    d major.minor version 52.0
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
            at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14
    2)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
            at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)

```
Exception in thread "main"

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException
: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.Executio
nException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.
internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\
java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

C:\Android\sdk

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupporte
d major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14
2)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)

Exception in thread "main"

Above you can see the error I tried to change the gradle but it does not work `enter code here`
```